# Using models controllers and view with a table that contains underscore

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called car_parts, and my controller is called CarPartsController, file is car_parts_controller.php. Then I have the model Car_Part, file name car_part.php. Here is the code

```
<?php
class CarPartsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Car_Parts';

    var $uses = array("Car_Part");

    function get_part($id)
    {
       $this->set('car_parts',$this->Car_Part->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Car_Part.car_id' == $id))));
       $this->layout = 'master_layout';
    }   
  }
```

?>

MODEL

```
<?php
class Car_Part extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'Car_Part';
 }
?>
```

View, this view is called get_part.ctp

```
   <?php
    print_r($car_parts);
    ?>
```

The problem I am having is that it says that it can not find the table car__parts (and it looks like if it had a double underscore but my table does not have a double underscore. Any ideas what I am doing wrong. I am new to Cake PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the underscore between Car & Part:

```
class CarPart extends AppModel {

  var $name = 'CarPart';

}
```